# Get _spPageContextInfo is not defined

Tags: rest

I have a regular .html file under root site and trying to make a REST call using _spPageContextInfo. What am I doing wrong here? Basically trying the code in this url but with _spPageContexInfo

https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/getting-started-with-rest-in-sharepoint-2013-part-i/

Comment: Please format your code with the code button or adding 4 spaces for each line

Comment: I tried the code button it does not seem to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work, as a plain HTML page is going to circumvent the master page, which is what causes all the dependent JavaScript objects to load.  Use a standard SharePoint page instead.